# How to interact with the blinded auction contract from web3.js

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, sha3

My question is about the [blind auction contract in the solidity examples](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#id2).

What is the right way to interact with the contract from web3.js? I tried this, but it does not give the right result.

```
var blinded_bid = web3.sha3(10, true, "abcd");
```

It would be great if someone could provide an example how to interact with that kind of contract using web3.

Comment: A little more code of what you tried would be helpful, such as how's the contract instantiated and how are you invoking the `bid ` method?

Comment: Did you deploy the contract yet?

Comment: Uzyn, how is you answer sending funds to the bid() function ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18383)

Comment: Thank you, I know but I cannot comment on Uzyn's post

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18383)

Comment: I know but I'm a noob and will never achieve 50 reputation

Answer (score 2):

For the [contract that you are referring to](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#id2), it involves 2 steps to make a bid:

1. First you hash your bid so that public cannot see your bid, but you can reveal and the contract can validate it after the bidding ends. This is done via `sha3()` call as what you have done.
2. Next, you submit the bid to the contract via the method `bid(bytes32 _blindedBid)`.

Here is sample code in JavaScript with web3:

```
// Instantiate the contract
var ABI = ...; // ABI of the contract
var address = '0x.............'; // Address of the contract
var contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(address);

// Step 1. Hash your bid
var blindedBid = sha3(10, true, 'abcd');

// Step 2: Submit the bid
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]; // Set a default account to send from
contract.bid(blindedBid);
```